# SUM() function gives incorrect output

Tags: mysql, sum

I have a single table named trust_fund:

[trust_fund table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fbhH7.png)

My Query is:
$sql = "SELECT SUM(available_balance) AS total_fund FROM trust_funds WHERE type = 'Admin'";

at first, it displays 100000000 which is correct, but when I update the table (transfered 500 from Admin to Agent), Admin available_balance become 99,999,504 and Agent becomes 500.

There is an extra 4 in Admin Balance. I tried transfering the 500 back to Admin Account and Admin Account becomes 100000008.

[The Output of the Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hzCNL.png)

I am confused because the tables shows correct values, 100000000 and 0, but running the query will give 100000004.

Please help

Table Definition

| Column | Type |
| --- | --- |
| id | INT(AI) |
| uid | Text |
| available_balance | Float |
| wallet_address | Text |
| type | Text |

Comment: This feels like an underlying data issue to me.

Comment: Please post your table definition, (as text, please, not a screen shot)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem arises from your use of the `FLOAT` data type for currency.

`FLOAT` is a poor choice for a currency column because it attracts errors from representation and rounding (See [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/14853083))

Use `INT` (or `BIGINT`) if you're working with integer values. Alternatively, use `DECIMAL` to store and work with exact decimal values.

Comment: Thanks a lot Sir.. It works... I changed the Float to Decimal, run the Query and there, the rows show 100000008... Thank you...

Comment: Thanks a lot Sir.. It works... I changed the Float to Decimal, run the Query and there, the rows show 100000008... Thank you...